# why does jquery $().find() return false positive

Tags: jquery

just a little puzzle why would ...

```
    $( document ).ready( function(){
if ($("body").find( ".bogusCrap" )) {
        alert("FOUND bogusCrap");
}

})
```

... return true?

The following check works as expected though:

```
$(".bogusCrap").length > 0
```

works as  expected

Comment: `if ({}) { alert('All objects are truthy.'); }` . `$("body").find( ".bogusCrap" ).length > 0` works as expected as well btw.

Comment: -1 because you could have found the answer yourself by spending one minute to look up [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/find/), and then you would have seen that `.find()` does not simply return a boolean value.

Comment: ... ahhhh, the joy of learning stuff the hard way. At least I run into this in someone else's code, out of habit I use the .length check ;-) Thank you bunches to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("body").find( ".bogusCrap" )` returns an empty array-like object. Objects, even when empty, aren't *falsy* values, they're *truthy* values. This means that in simple terms, an empty object (or an empty array) is equal to `true`.

You can try it yourself:

```
if ( [] )
    alert("True");

if ( {} )
    alert("True");
```

As pointed out by Felix Kling in the comments below, `$("body").find( ".bogusCrap" )` actually returns a [jQuery object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/), however what I've said above still applies.

Comment: To be more precise, it returns a jQuery object.